# How to set up an Async task from an activity in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask

I have an activity that calls a class and runs a function in that class like so:

```
        for (i in 0 until questions) {
            droll.droolCalls(sign)
        }
```

This can sometimes run forever as it has to generate a bunch of random numbers, so I want it to be able to run in the background. I wrote an AsyncTask that looks like this:

```
class MyAsync(
    private val droll: CreateLayout,
    private val questions: Int, private val sign:Int,
    var progressBar: ProgressBar,
    var layoutProgress: LinearLayout,
    var layoutMain: LinearLayout
) :
    AsyncTask<String, Int, CreateLayout>() {


    var progress = 0
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): CreateLayout {
        for (i in 0 until questions) {
            droll.droolCalls(sign)
        }
        return droll
    }

    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Int?) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
        progressBar.incrementProgressBy(progress * 10)
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: CreateLayout?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        layoutProgress.visibility = View.GONE
        layoutMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

}
```

However, when i call the drollclass

`MyAsync(droll, totalQuestions,sign, progressBar, Loading, mainLayout).execute("hello")`

i get an error from other functions that require drool to run.

this one for example `insert_point.addView(droll.makeTextView(numberOfQuestions - 1))` gives me a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0` error because insert_point not getting the data from droll because the Async didn't run? however if i take it out of the Async the for loop our of the Async it works fine.

the whole structure looks something like this

```
class mainclass{

MyAsync(droll, totalQuestions,sign, progressBar, Loading, mainLayout).execute("hello")
insert_point.addView(droll.makeTextView(numberOfQuestions - 1))


class MyAsync(
    private val droll: CreateLayout,
    private val questions: Int, private val sign:Int,
    var progressBar: ProgressBar,
    var layoutProgress: LinearLayout,
    var layoutMain: LinearLayout
) :
    AsyncTask<String, Int, CreateLayout>() {


    var progress = 0
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): CreateLayout {
        for (i in 0 until questions) {
            droll.droolCalls(sign)
        }
        return droll
    }

    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Int?) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
        progressBar.incrementProgressBy(progress * 10)
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: CreateLayout?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        layoutProgress.visibility = View.GONE
        layoutMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It is not clear from your code the underlying `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Why are you passing the same `Int` value `sign` multiple times in your loop? If you are asynchronously mutating something in your `CreateLayout` (`drool`) class that is acted upon synchronously in your `Activity` then you will surely run into problems. You should be using your `CreateLayout` object supplied in `onPostExecute(result: CreateLayout?)` which guarantees the async task has completed processing for use with your `ViewGroup` object `insert_point`.

Comment: @MarkKeen thanks! I will look into this and try it!

Comment: @MarkKeen my dude, post it as a solution if you want A check. that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package www.binexmining.co.`in`.binexmining.binexmining.uam.view.activity

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.annotation.MainThread
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.row_referraluser.view.*
import www.binexmining.co.`in`.binexmining.R

class AsynTaskKotlinMain : Activity()
{

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        MyAssyn().execute("Pre-Executing Param Put here...","Param For Doinbackgroun")
    }

}

class  MyAssyn : AsyncTask<Any, Any, Any>()
{

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Any?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Any?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
    }
}
```